# If request is not null statement in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

How to execute statement in query only if request exists?
Example: $request->type (if NULL search everywhere if not check only arriving filghts)

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
               ->if($requst->type = NULL) return all; else { ->where('type', $request->type)
               ->get();
```

Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split your code reasigning the query like

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc');
if($requst->type != NULL) {
    $flights = $flights->where('type', $request->type);
}
return $flights->get();
```